# Check if table row contains two things?

Tags: sql, upload, contains

I want to check if a file that is uploaded belongs to the currently logged in user, so others can't edit it.  I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$query = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id='$file_id' AND userid=".$_SESSION['userid']);
$query->execute();
if ($query->rowCount() != 1){
    echo "This file is not yours.";
}
else {
    echo "EDIT";
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code you've got?

Comment: I'm so sory, I was not $_GET-ing the $file_id, thank you for your help though!